# Browser cache: Json response

Tags: json, node.js, express, browser-cache, etag

i tried to cache a json response from an api request using the Etag.
I'm calling something like this http://localhost:3000/api/config and getting:

**Response Headers:**
Cache-Control:public, max-age=31557600
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:11
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 13 May 2015 11:41:52 GMT
ETag:"94d52736bcd99b1ac771f13b1bbdf622"
X-Powered-By:Express

Resonse: {id: 1}

I expected the browser to cache the response and to send the Etag with the next request triggert by "f5". But this isn't the case.

**Request Headers 2nd request:**
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3000
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36

So is it impossible to cache pure json response, getting by a direct api requests?
 Or do i miss something.

The api is an node js test implemantation done with express:

```
router.get('/config', function(req, res) {
    var eTag = crypto.createHash('md5').update(JSON.stringify(config)).digest('hex');
    res.setHeader('ETag', '"' + eTag + '"');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=31557600');
});
```

Testet with chrom(42.x) and firefox(37.x)

Thx for response.

Comment: Yes you can cache JSON responses. At first glance it seems like a browser side issue. You shouldn't be sending `pragma: no-cache` in the request headers unless you disabled cache in chrome debugger tools or elsewhere in your browser settings. How are you issuing this request?

Comment: I just call the api route, using the browser url bar. I also tried to call the route using a script tag like <script src="localhost:3000/api/config"></script> returning a javascript object var config = {...}.

Comment: I read that it should be possible with an ajax request but i need a direct call.

Comment: I found a hint, i used res.end() to send response maybe thats the problem, i will try that again on monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this code seems to work for me:

```
router.get('/config', function(req, res) {
    var eTag = crypto.createHash('md5').update(JSON.stringify(config)).digest('hex');

    if (req.headers['if-none-match'] && req.headers['if-none-match'] === '"' + eTag + '"') {
        res.status(304);
        res.end();
    } else {
        res.setHeader('ETag', '"' + eTag + '"');
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=31557600');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(config));
    }
});
```

Calling the api using browser url bar http://localhost:3000/api/config

Comment: you must be using an older version of express? express handles etags for you by default in more recent versions. You shouldn't need that if-block. See here: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.set.

Comment: Using express 4, I get the 304 header, and the content type and the etag, back with just:
router.get( '/config', function( req, res ) {

    res.send( config );

} );

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I did figured it out  by myself. I'm not aware why it doesn't worked at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be using chrome.
Chrome should include the following header in the request after "f5":

```
If-None-Match:"94d52736bcd99b1ac771f13b1bbdf622"
```

If you don't see this, check the chrome settings / General and make sure that "Disable cache (while DevTools is open) is *not* checked:

[image: Disable cache not checked in Chrome dev tools]

Comment: Disable cache (while DevTools is open) is not checked.

Comment: @LukasBonzelett what library are you using to call the API? JQuery?

Comment: I do a direct call its no ajax call.

Comment: You call the API by typing a URL into a browser?

Comment: Yes, or i call it within a script tag as resource. The Api request returns a javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery we can use the ifModified option:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   ifModified: true,
   url: "http://localhost:3000/api/config"
}).then(function(data) {
   . . .
});
```